# How can I fix "Error: Cannot match any routes" while navigating to tabs after a Login?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I try to make an app only accessible after Login using Ionic 4(4.10.2 with Angular 7.3.1). After following this tutorial (https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-login-angular/) I can't go to the part of my app which uses ion-tabs. Chrome always shows this in the console log: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'members/tab1'"

The app will use a Laravel-backend, and I want to use tokens for securing the connection. But to this point I only use a mock token from the tutorial. When I try to link to anything different then the tabs after Login, it works just fine, but that doesn't really solve my problem.

Routing in app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './public/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './public/register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
  {
    path: 'members',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: './members/member-routing.module#MemberRoutingModule'
  },

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

member-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'message', loadChildren: './message/message.module#MessagePageModule' },
  { path: 'playerview', loadChildren: './playerview/playerview.module#PlayerviewPageModule' },
  { path: 'playerlist', loadChildren: './playerlist/playerlist.module#PlayerlistPageModule' },
  { path: 'teamview', loadChildren: './teamview/teamview.module#TeamviewPageModule' },
  { path: 'teamlist', loadChildren: './teamlist/teamlist.module#TeamlistPageModule' },
  { path: 'teammanagement', loadChildren: './teammanagement/teammanagement.module#TeammanagementPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MemberRoutingModule { }
```

InitialiseApp from app.component.ts:

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();
    this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
      if (state) {
        this.router.navigate(['members', 'tabs']);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Routing in tabs.router.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab4',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            canActivate: [AuthGuard],
            loadChildren: '../tab4/tab4.module#Tab4PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    redirectTo: '/members/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

My mock-login button in login.page.html:

```
<ion-button (click)="login()" expand="block"  routerLink="../members/tab1">Login</ion-button>
```

After you click the Login-button, I want the mock login to remember that you are logged in and that you can see the tab navigation and the pages.

If I should add the auth.guard.ts or anything else, please tell me. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is totally correct, you have no route `members/tab1`, so I don't know where you are trying to navigate actually :)

Comment: This was just the last thing I tried before asking. I tried members/tabs, members/tabs/tab1 or other tabs, and I tried it without members :/

Comment: Can you create a project on https://stackblitz.com and share the code? You may not be able to create an Ionic 4 project. I suggest you to fork this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic-4 and create the folders according to your project and share the link here so that it will be easier to help you

Comment: Seems you might need to use `members/tabs/tabs/tab1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the link in your `routerLink` to `../members/tabs/tab1`.

Comment: I tried various combinations already. This changes the error to "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'members/tabs/tab1'"